# MS Access runtime 3011 - turns "!" into "$"

Tags: ms-access, vba

Any assistance with this will be very much appreciated.

I'm trying to link a table in Access to a spreadsheet, and specifying file, sheet and range to link to.

[image: weird character conversion]

As you can see from the diagram, the string (Target) that specifies the tab and range debug fine as BGM!A1:D200000, but in the error message, Access has replaced  "!" with "$", and the whole thing bugs out.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign your range `BGM!A1:D200000` a *Named Range* in Excel, then link the name of this.